# Help.with stuttering audio

Tags: sound

Running two asrock beebox nucs (intel cherryview) which all of a sudden will not stop stuttered audio playback.  Both were running 15.10.  I just upgraded one to 16.04 and still stuttering.

They had been working for about a year each and then just all of a sudden all audio/video playback is stuttering.  DVD files from my nas, YouTube, kodi streams ...the video seems smooth but the sound stutters so bad it silence.

They are identical machines, cherryview 1.04ghz x2 proc, intel graphic, 8gb ram.  I can only surmise it was some update that hosed them.